# How to dynamically change a Model attribute in a controller?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I have two tables `users` and `users_metadata`, where a single user `hasMany` metadata.

When I'm fetching all of the users, I want to be able to select certain fields, some of which exist in the metadata table.

```
users - id:1
users_metadata - user_id:1, key:username, value: MyUsername
users_metadata - user_id:1, key:birthday, value: 2017-11-16
```

Through the url, I can add on a fields attribute which lists what fields I want to select rather than all of them.

```
/api/v1/users?fields=username
```

What I'd like to be able to do is, instead of fetching all the metadata is to just fetch the metadata which is listed in the fields.

```
// Are we selecting all the fields?
if(!is_array($fields))
{
    // We are not, so lets build an array
    $fields = explode(',', $fields);

    // Loop through the users
    foreach($users as $user)
    {
        // Loop through the fields
        foreach($fields as $field)
        {
            // Try to fetch it as metadata
            if(array_key_exists($field, $user->metadata->toArray()))
            {
                $metadata[] = $field;
            }
        }

        // Adjust the user metadata
        $user->metadata = $user->metadata->filter(function($value, $key) use($metadata)
        {
            return in_array($key, $metadata);
        });
    }
}
```

However this isn't updating my data with the new metadata, and when I dump the user data I'm still getting all my original metadata rather than just the username.

```
/**
 * Fetch all the metadata for a user.
 *
 * @return objects
 */
public function metadata()
{
    return $this->hasMany(UserMetadata::class);
}

    /**
     * Fetch the metadata as an attribute.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getMetadataAttribute()
    {
        return $this->metadata()->get()->flatMap(function($values)
        {
            return [$values['key'] => $values['value']];
        });
    }

    /**
     * Update the metadata attribute.
     *
     * @param varied $value     The new metadata attribute.
     * @return void
     */
    public function setMetadataAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['metadata'] = $value;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you use the `only()` method at the collection level?

For example, you have your `fields` array from the URL.  In this case it is only the one metadata field.

```
$fields = ['username'];
```

Then get all the users:

`$users_all = User::all();` or however you wish to get the collection of users.

Then use the `only()` method to filter the results to just the fields you need:

```
$filtered = $users_all->only($fields);
```

Then return the filtered collection:

```
$filtered->all();
```

From:  https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-only